# Is there a way to apply a function to dimension 0 of a tensorflow array having the shape (None, 2)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

I have a very technical question related to `TensorFlow`.

I have a `TensorFlow matrix` having a dimension of `(None, 2)`. I need to apply a function, say some_function, only on Dimension 0 of the matrix i.e. over all rows. The issue is dimension 0 is a None type *(it is dynamic as it depends on the input size being fed to the `NN model`)*, and it gives an error showing None is not an integer type. There are two `tf functions`: `tf.map_fn` and `tf.scan` to iterate over a `Tensorflow array`. But both won't work over a None dimension.

Maybe you could check it by defining a test TensorFlow array of shape `(None, 2)` and try applying any test function to the first dimension. Any help/input would be appreciated!

Comment: Which TF version are you using?

Comment: Tensorflow 2.0.0

Comment: Usually `None` in this context means that that dimension is arbitrary. Often that dimension is reserved for the number of training examples, meaning that any function you apply is going to be applied to each element of your data. Perhaps some data preprocessing could help you deal with this?

Comment: @ManavMishra, can you share code how you defined a Tensor with a `None` dimension? Because you cannot define `tf.Tensor` with `None` dimensions (you were able to use placeholders to achieve this in TF 1). Keras model output is the only instance I can think, where you'd end up with a None dimension.

Comment: I have a NN model defined using tf.keras taking in 2 inputs and giving 2 outputs. So my model.output is a tensor with shape (None,2). You could think the outputs to be x and y, my goal is to apply a function f(x,y) that works over all the inputs.

Comment: @tchainzzz That is exactly what I am stuck on. I need to apply a function over each element of my 2-dimensional data. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a keras model output, if I try to do the following,

```
res2 = tf.map_fn(lambda y: y*2, model.output)
```

You get,

> TypeError: 'Tensor' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

But, the following would work,

```
# Inital model that produces the output you want to map
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, input_shape=(2,)))

res = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.map_fn(lambda y: y*2, x))(model.output)
```

Then you define a new model, and use that to get the result of the `tf.map_fn`.

```
model2 = tf.keras.Model(inputs=model.inputs, outputs=res)
print(model2.predict(np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])))
```

**PS**: But this is nothing to do with the first dimension being `None`. `tf.map_fn` can deal with `None` dimension just fine. You can verify this by running `tf.map_fn` on a `tf.placeholder([None,2])` in TF 1.x.

Because it is iteratively applying a function over that dimension and does not need to know the size to do so.

Comment: I have two questions:
1. Shouldn't the inputs be model.output rather than model.input since I am using the NN output as function arguments?
2. My actual function is: 
`def tf2(vec):
    [x,y] = vec;
    x1 = tf.math.atanh(x);
    y1 = tf.math.atanh(y);
    return tf.math.exp(-x1**2 + -y1**2)*(x1**2 + y1**2)`
And in this scenario,  res = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.map_fn(lambda y: tf2(y), x))(model.output)ails. How do I fix this?